# How do I call a method after creating a MaterialApp?

Tags: dart, flutter

From what I understand, creating a MaterialApp instance creates the Navigator along with a couple of other UI features. When my app launches I want to run a method to check if the user logged in and if not display a login page. How would I go about doing this? Below is the start of my main.dart

```
final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

String _email;
String _password;

void _submit() {
final form = formKey.currentState;

if (form.validate()) {
  form.save();

  // Email & password matched our validation rules
  // and are saved to _email and _password fields.
  _performLogin();
  }
}

void _performLogin() {
// This is just a demo, so no actual login here.
  final snackbar = new SnackBar(
    content: new Text('Email: $_email, password: $_password'),
  );

  scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    key: scaffoldKey,
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text('Validating forms'),
    ),
    body: new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: new Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: new Column(
          children: [
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
              validator: (val) =>
                  !val.contains('@') ? 'Not a valid email.' : null,
              onSaved: (val) => _email = val,
            ),
            new TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
              validator: (val) =>
                  val.length < 6 ? 'Password too short.' : null,
              onSaved: (val) => _password = val,
              obscureText: true,
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              onPressed: _submit,
              child: new Text('Login'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you can use `FutureBuilder` to check your methods, I am using `FirebaseAuth` here:

```
    return new FutureBuilder(future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> user) {
           
 ///Check if user data != null
            
              return user.hasData ? new HomeScreen(....) : new LoginScreen(...)
    ......
```

You can also check the [flutter architecture pattern](http://fluttersamples.com/) to manage user auth state in a better way.

[Also here is a useful example on how to manage Firebase with Redux library.](https://marcinszalek.pl/flutter/reduxing-flutter/)

Answer (score 1):

You can separate your Login and Home pages into two separate Widgets, and then use them conditionally in the `build` method of your top level widget.

Something like:

```
@override
build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Container(
    child: isLoggedIn ? HomeWidget : LoginWidget
  )
}
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I go about running the method to check if the user is logged in when the app is first opened?